The \cref doesn't work inside the "split" environment
I'm doing this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand\foo[2]{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{#1}#2}
\crefformat{foo}{Foo~#2#1#3}

\begin{equation*}
Set: \foo{a}{test}
Ref: \cref{a}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}

The \cref works just fine.
Now, I'm putting this equation inside split:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand\foo[2]{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{#1}#2}
\crefformat{foo}{Foo~#2#1#3}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
Set: \foo{a}{test} & \\
Ref: \cref{a} & \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}

I'm getting ?? instead of the reference.

Please explain your use case for wishing to use \cref in this manner.

@Mico it's just a toy example, my use case is much larger, but I don't want to show it here, for the sake of brevity

There are two problems:

the counter should only be stepped once (split does two passes over the material);
split changes the meaning of \label and you should use the original command, saved in \cref@label (if cleveref were not involved, \ltx@label should be the choice).

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{foo}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \refstepcounter{foo}\cref@label{#1}%
  \fi
  #2%
}
\makeatother
\crefformat{foo}{Foo~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
Set: \foo{a}{test} & \\
Ref: \text{\cref{a}} & \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


I believe you know what your aim is, I can't guess.

Many thanks, it works! However, it works only if the label contains a single letter. With the label, for example, aaa, it doesn't work. Maybe you know, why and how to fix?

@yegor256 Use \cref@label instead of \ltx@label.
